# Load LAS files in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, import, lidar, las

Is it possible to open LAS files within MapInfo?

If so, how is accomplished in MapInfo 10.0?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not natively. This can however be done with plugins to Mapinfo such as Encom 3D

http://www.encom.com.au/template2.asp?pageid=10

Comment: I take it that plugin costs unlike the MapBasic plugin?

Comment: I've used Engage 3D Pro by Encom and, yes, it does cost.  From memory, between $2000 and $3000 Australian Dollars.  It's a  pretty decent program, though.  If you don't want to pay top dollar, have a look at Global Mapper which is significantly cheaper.  Also, there are several open source alternatives and you should be able to convert for use in MapInfo fairly painlessly.